# Chrome - Cannot read property 'status' of undefined even with check first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see a lot similar questions for this particular javascript error, but my issue is I've already implemented the "fixes" and it still occurs, but only randomly.

The error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Before referencing the status property like so json.status, in all instances I precede it with:

```
if ( typeof json.status != 'undefined' )
```

So in theory, there should be no reason for it to ever throw that error if I'm checking first in all situations.

When I click the line number it's referencing in the console, it goes to a blank screen, so it's been hard to troubleshoot. If I expand open the error stack thing, it references my jquery dataTables a bunch, but I don't know if that's because something is failing prior to it or not.

How can I troubleshoot this deeper, or catch that error properly so it doesn't halt all my AJAX calls that come after it? (requires a refresh when it happens...)

Comment: Not `.status` is undefined, but `json` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuz you're not providing the full code, I cannot understand so clearly your situation.

Anyway, the error simply showing that `json` is **undefined** (due to something wrong in the coding logic, ...).

To quick fix the error, you can change your code to do null-check for `json` as well:

```
if (json && (typeof json.status != 'undefined')) {...}
```

Or a better way:

```
if (json && json.status) {...}
```

Comment: Wow! I don't know why it took seeing @Bergi's and your explanation of it being "json" itself that wasn't defined for it to register for me! Makes perfect sense. I'll that check as well.

Comment: is there an actual difference between if ( json.status ) and if ( json.status != 'undefined' ) or no?

Comment: @SourceMatters Yes it's different, cuz it does not only check for `undefined`, but for `falsy value` of javascript (`undefined`, `null', `0`, `empty space`,..). See this for more information: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/